# Convert a column value(s) in SpatialpolygonDataframe into raster image

Tags: r

I need help with converting a variable or column values in a spatial polygon into a raster image. I have spatial data of administrative units with income(mean) information for each unit. I want to convert this information into raster for further analysis.

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
r <- raster(ncol=5,nrow=15) 
r.inc <- rasterize(DK,r,field=DK@data[,2],fun=mean)
```

Where SP is the spatial polygon and the mean income for each spatial unit stored in column 2 of the SpatialPolygonDataframe. Can anyone help with a function or code of how to rasterise the values in the column of interest? An example of the spatialpolygondataframe (created) and my attempt to rasterize the data are below

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
url = "https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/landsdele?format=geojson"
geofile = tempfile()
download.file(url, geofile)
DK <- rgdal::readOGR(geofile)
DK@data = subset(DK@data, select = c(navn))
DK@data$inc = runif(11, min=5000, max=80000)
require(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=5,nrow=15) 
r.inc <- rasterize(DK,r,field=DK@data[,2],fun=mean)
plot(r.inc)
```

Thank you.

Acknowledgement: The code for creating the sample SPDF was sourced from Mikkel Freltoft Krogsholm (link below).

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/easy-maps-denmark-r-mikkel-freltoft-krogsholm/?trk=read_related_article-card_title

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example including data. This will increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: thank Andrew, I've edited the question to include sample data and my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that makes a raster.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
url <- "https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/landsdele?format=geojson"
geofile <- tempfile()
download.file(url, geofile)
DK <- rgdal::readOGR(geofile)
r_dk <- raster(DK, nrows = 100, ncols = 100)      # Make a raster of the same size as the spatial polygon with many cells
DK$inc <- runif(nrow(DK), min=5000, max=80000)    # Add some fake income data
rr <- rasterize(DK, r_dk, field='inc')            # Rasterize the polygon into the raster - fun = 'mean' won't make any difference
                                                                                             
plot(rr)
```

[image]

The original raster was the size of the whole Earth so I think Denmark was being averaged to nothing. I resolved this by making an empty raster based on the extent of the DK spatial polygons with 100x100 cells. I also simplified the code. Generally, if you find yourself using `@` with spatial data manipulation, it's a sign that there might be a simpler way. Because the resolution of the raster is much larger than the size of each DK region, taking the average doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Also, thank you so the insightful explanation.